# Linear regression or gaussian process?

Tags: regression, linear, gaussian-process

I'm trying to understand what kind of model I should use to represent the following toy problem. I'd be grateful for some pointers to what model(s) would be apt.

"Every day, three children love to play with many different things. They also do their best tidying up at they end of the day but they don't always manage to completely succeed at that. So every week their dad takes a bag, makes a round through the house and cleans the last few things up. He puts this bag on the scale and measures its weight."

Let us denote by $x$ the number of days since the last big clean (in the example 7 days every time) and by $y$ the weight. I think the relationship can be modelled quite easily as $y=\theta x + \varepsilon$, but there's one thing that I don't quite understand. If I'm not mistaken, the sum of normally distributed random variables implies that $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, x\sigma^2)$ which makes it depend on $x$. Somehow that doesn't seem right to me.

Should I divide everything by $x$ to have a model $y'=\theta+\varepsilon$? Or is a different model better suited to represent the temporal aspect (a Gaussian Process perhaps)?

Comment: In the standard OLS setting, $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ which implies $y\sim N(\theta x,\sigma^2)$. The conditional mean does depend on $x$. In your example, if $x$ is 7 days every time, you essentially have a constant and you wouldn't need linear regression to study your problem?

Comment: Should’ve explained I’m trying to model the pile of toys left lying around over time (and answer questions like at what time is the pile with 5% chance expected to exceed one waste bag?) so 7 days is just a sampling thing. Using $y \sim \mathcal N(\theta x, \sigma^2)$, how do you express that the variance increases over time?

Comment: So this model precludes that possibility. If you are imposing a functional form on $\sigma^2$
, you should probably turn towards a distributional regression set up, where you parametrize the mean weight over the 7 day period, and the variance over that 7 day period. Look into GAMLSS? If the function you are hoping to model is somewhat cyclic, they have cyclic P-splines built into the package that might be useful, assuming that the measurements have some periodicity to them ...